# PHP: render iframe on the server side

Tags: php, iframe, server-side-rendering

I understand that an iframe is rendered by the browser engine
is there a way to render the full HTML on the server side and serve it to the front end?
I tried the [PHP's file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function and the `srcdoc` attribute for the iframe

#### This simply downloads the content of the page and makes it unusable

```
<?= file_get_contents('http://dns_blocked_by_isp.com'); ?>
```

#### And this renders a non-working iframe

```
<iframe srcdoc="<?= file_get_contents('http://dns_blocked_by_isp.com'); ?>"
        frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no
        allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

So am basically looking for an alternative of `runat="server"` in ASP.NET but for PHP if possible

#### Motivation:

My ISP blocked the DNS address where I get my iframe source from, but my server runs on a different region which means it can download the content just fine and the urls in the iframe has `-cdn.com` suffix which in turn is not blocked by the ISP

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that `file_get_contents('http://dns_blocked_by_isp.com');` is returning the HTML from the target page? The fact that `srcdoc="<?= file_get_contents('http://dns_blocked_by_isp.com'); ?>"` is no shocker because 99.9% of pages will return content with `"` characters in it, and you're not escaping double-quotes. Also, you are better off using a PHP proxy page rather than `srcdoc` as browser support is an issue with `srcdoc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around browser support issues, you'd probably be better off setting up a PHP proxy page (i.e. a script on your server that just fetches the remote page and serves the source directly as a page from your server), but I suspect that the issue you're running into is just that the `"` characters being returned from the remote page are breaking the `srcdoc` attribute. Let's say that the remote file looks like:

`<p class="worldclass">Hello World</p>`

Then your example would result in:

`<iframe srcdoc="<p class="worldclass">Hello World</p>"`

So the the value of `srcdoc` is just `<p class=`

You just need to escape the code appropriately:

`<iframe srcdoc="<?= htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://dns_blocked_by_isp.com')); ?>"
        frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no
        allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen>
</iframe>`